# 60 Sec shutdown delay in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome, shutdown, gsettings

I want to remove 60 sec delay when i press power button. I used "gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt false". After i entered that line in terminal it works except lock on screen.  So i can't shutdown my pc without 60 sec delay on lock on screen.

Comment: Are you using the power button to shut down the OS?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i want to do. I want to shut my pc down with the power button.

Comment: That WILL corrupt the OS you are playing a dangerous game doing this.

Comment: Why? Is it not the same with the clicking shutdown? What is the difference and i also need this at my project.

Comment: Using a proper software shut down closes all files and deletes any tmp files. I suggest you do some research on why a proper shutdown is necessary in all OS.